# Input/Set/Change HTML img src with Node JS

Tags: html, node.js

I have a NodeJS server which allows users to upload images to a directory. I'm trying to build a system that will get an image in this directory depending on the currently authenticated user and output it to an HTML Page

I'm trying to find a way to set the `img src` through NodeJS but am unable to do so.

```html
<html>
<body>
<img src="user1.png" />
</body>
</html>
```

Everywhere I have checked, the Front-end has the filename explicitly entered into the `img src` tag, but since I need this tag to be set according to the user I can't enter the link of a single image in the tag. Should I make a separate HTML page for each image or is their a different solution to this problem through Node?

I have also stored the path to each image in a MySQL table with adequate measures recognise it for the required user. Is there a way I can use this to input into the `img src` tag?

```
module.exports.getImage= function(req,res){
    var imageid = req.body.id;
    var imagesql = 'SELECT path FROM Image WHERE id = ?';
    var imageinsert = [imageid];
    certsql = mysql.format(imagesql, imageinsert);
    connection.query(imagesql, function(error,results, fields){
        if(error){
            console.log(error)
            res.status(401).send('query error');
        }
        else{
            console.log(results)
            res.status(200).send(results);
        }
    })
}
```

The snippet above gives the path in results.

I am using express and storing the user token in cookies.

Ejs didn't work, is there any other way I could get solve this problem?

Comment: you can use pug or handlebars templating engine and pass your image to the template file and render it.

Answer (score 1):

> Store some type of **user id in session** and get data according. Load
>   the above `html` in ejs view engine and set the src attribute as file
>   gotten from the directory.

Comment: Is there a way I can call the ejs file in a controller instead of the server file? I have a getImage controller which I import and use in the server.js file. The getImage controller currently runs connection.query to retrieve the file path.

Comment: I have provided the getImage controller. How should I write my ejs file and then call it here? (I have never worked with ejs or other template engines and am also fairly new to NodeJs)

Comment: `res.render('your_html_view_file', {'image': imageFromDB})`

and at your view side
 
`<img src="<%= imageFromDB %> ">`

**`<%= %>` is ejs formate like php has `<?php ?>`**

Comment: Here, imageFromDB will be the full path of the file right?

Comment: exactly...  sorry a little correction for your image tag

`<img src = "<%= image %> ">`

Comment: I am getting the following error:  

Error: Module "html" does not provide a view engine.  

I have set up ejs as follows:  

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

Comment: your file **extension** must be **ejs**... like `fileNmae.ejs`

Comment: I am now getting a broken image as the output. The kind where the image doesn't load and has the broken image icon.

Comment: I think my setup for ejs is faulty/incomplete. Could you advise what all steps I should take?

Comment: simply use `npm install ejs` it will install or update your ejs module

Comment: And the setup of views directory? I have placed my .ejs file in the directory and then set it in server.js as:  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views'); app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); and called it in the getImage controller as: res.render('view', {'image': imgPath) Am I making any mistakes here or missing anything out?